# Error while creating new column with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(data.table)    
library(dplyr)
col1<-rep(c("a":"d"),3)
col2<-rep(c(1:4),3)
col3<-rep(c(1:4),3)
col4<-rep(c(1:4),3)
df<-data.table(col1,col2,col3,col4)


v1=c("A","B")
V2=c(1,2)
table<-as.data.table(v1,V2)

ND<-select(data,col1,col2,col3)%>%
  filter(col1==as.character(table$V1))%>%
  mutate(mget(table$v1)=as.numeric(col2)*as.numeric(table$V2))
```

And I get this error

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  filter(col1==as.character(table$V1))%>%
  mutate(mget(table$v1)="
```

Can anyone help me with the error I get? I am trying to create a new column with the name of the obs of v1 column.

Comment: You can't define the name function arguments like that. See `vignette("nse")`, and the `nse` tag here on SO.

Comment: 1- Can you add your desired result and 2- Your code has many typos and doesn't run properly (even the first lines)

Comment: @PLapointe just forgot to add library(data.table) I just added to the script. It should be fine now